# Downloading and parsing json in Swift with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

Sorry I am quite new to this and they're may be something glaringly obvious that is going over my head but I am getting the following error message with this code:

"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value."

```
   var jsonReceived = Alamofire.request(.GET, getJsonURL).responseJSON {
        (request, response, jsonData, error) in
        if jsonData == nil {
            println(error)
        } else {
            println(jsonData)
            var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
            println(jsonResult)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line is the error occuring on? `jsonData` should already be parsed into a dictionary. No need to do the `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` bit... that happens behind the scenes in `Alamofire`. Also you shouldn't be setting `var jsonReceived = ...`. The JSON is parsed and passed into the closure as `jsonData` in your example.

Comment: The var jsonResult line. I see, how would I go about accessing jsonData then in your opinion?

Comment: After the `println(jsonData)` line, you can go ahead and do anything you'd like with `jsonData`. For example, call a callback function to update the view. I can post an example below if that would help?

Comment: Yes please, that would be great if you could!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for simplicity, I've put the `Alamofire.request` code into the `viewDidLoad()`. You could put it wherever you want.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, getJsonURL).responseJSON {
            (request, response, jsonData, error) in
            if error != nil {
                println(error)
            } else if let json = jsonData as? [String:AnyObject] {
                println(json)

                // call a function with the new data. 
                self.processNewData(json)

                // or you could just use the json object here
                if let str = json["foo"] as? String {
                    self.myButton.setTitle(str, forState: .Normal)
                }
            } else {
                println("Failed to cast JSON to [String:AnyObject]")
            }
        }
}

func processNewData(json: [String:AnyObject]){
    // do whatever you want here with the parsed JSON
    if let str = json["bar"] as? String {
        myLabel.text = str
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's definitely cleared things up a bit more. I'm taking the 'call a function' route with this however when I try to call a new function with the new data, it tells me 'View Controller' does not have a member named 'processJsonData.'

Comment: Hmmm. Are the function names matching? And you have to add `self.` when calling the function from within a closure.

Comment: They are. Sorry, I forgot to mention that all the Alamofire code is inside a searchBarSearchButtonClicked function. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Ah sorry! I put the func inside the searchBarSearchButtonClicked function. You can tell I'm new to Swift haha. I'm going to play around with it and let you know happens.

Comment: Ok no worries! Glad you figured it out. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help you hero. I was just wondering if you could help me out one more time. 

    func processJsonData(json: [String:AnyObject]) {
        if let str = json["latitude"]! as? String {
            latitudeString = str
            println(latitudeString)
        }
    }

println(json) from above prints out:
[longitude: 0.1275, latitude: 51.5072]

and when I call the processJsonData function, it doesn't seem to be saving the latitude part to latitudeString variable. Any idea on this? Also I'll be doing the same with longitude.

Comment: I don't think you want to have the exclamation point in `json["latitude"]!`.. the `if let...` unwraps the optional. Does it execute `println(latitudeString)` line? If so, what does it print there?

Comment: There is nothing printing to the console so I don't think the variable latitudeString is saving.

Comment: Hmmm well it sounds like it's not able to cast json["latitude"] to a String... Maybe try casting to a Float? Also, I'd check to make sure json["latitude"] isn't nil.

Comment: It turns out when I println json["latitude"] and ["longitude"], they are the values they are supposed to be. Optional(0.1275) and Optional(51.5072) respectively.